# number formatting is changed erroneously to time/date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with numerous formats, mostly time and whole number.  Data validation is present to assure proper formats.  certain fields can be selected and VBA programmatically inserts the system time to the selected cell.  This works perfectly and is very helpful when using this sheet.  The problem occurs if a cell that should have a whole number (and definitely not a time) is accidently selected, then the "enter system time" code is run.  This changes the format of that cell to time/date.  said in another way, A1 is formatted for Number, 0 decimal places.  A1 is selected and the "Enter system time" macro is run.  The macro is not affected by the data validation rule that would otherwise prohibit anything but a whole number between 1 and 999.  Now that the formatting is changed by VBA (somehow), when you enter, say, 5 into that (formerly) number-formatted cell, displayed is 1/5/1900 0:00.  Because this is a compiled workbook, the change is permanent; the cell format cannot be changed back.
so, my question is:  Is there a workaround?  Is there a way to prevent this sort of format change? is there a way to unlock the cell if the format is wrong?  Is there any sort of suggested method to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this.  The correct number formatting command is:
    If Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]h:mm AM/PM;@" Then...

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the format is a number with 0 decimal places using the `NumberFormat` property of the `Range` object like:

```
If Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0" Then
    'Some Code
End If
```

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff196401.aspx for more information on formats

Comment: This is close to what i'm looking for and I am confident that my problem has a solution, but this doesn't work

Comment: This is close to what i'm looking for and I am confident that my problem has a solution, but this doesn't work.  furthermore, rather than just checking a specified range for the formatting, the code must check whatever cell is selected.  I hope that's possible.  My current code reads "If range ("f14").numberformat = "[$-en-US]h:mm AM/PM" then.."  It doesn't matter what format I specify, the code doesn't run.  Furthermore, as I said, I want this code to run for any cell on the page, not just a specified range.  thank you.

Comment: Please, if you could provide an example, it would be easier to give you a more directed answer.

Comment: Sub wristwatch()
If Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM" Then
ActiveCell = Now()
Else
MsgBox "You cannot enter a Time/Date here.  The cell that you have selected expects a number, not a time.", vbCritical, "FlightPlan for Profits PRO-flex III"
End If
End Sub
This is my current code.  no matter what I have put as the string for NumberFormat, the code rejects it and skips the Now() line.  Geez.